# LoopTools : Wierd shape instead of being a simple circle

Tags: modeling

Anyone can help me a bit with a LoopTool issue? I am trying to turn some square circles I did on a model into rounded one but each time I press the circle option in LoopTools instead of making it look like in the third picture I attached (the expectation one) it just deforms my model as in picture two I am not sure what I am doing wrong and how can I fix it? How can I solve the problem of achieving the rounded circles without having all the areas affected?
(I am new to blender so I am lacking some basic knowledge regarding how the program functions .. please explain the solution as you would do to a newbie) 
Thank you very much for your support!

This is how my work looks before applying anything [ I want to turn that square into a round shape)
[image]

This is how it looks after applying the circle effect from LoopTools ( far from what i want and all the edges are affected.. not sure what I did wrong)
[image]

This is exactly how i would like it to look but i can't seem to be able to get the square to a circle shape
[image]

Comment: Hello :). This is a bug, [already reported](https://developer.blender.org/T73597) and [fixed](https://developer.blender.org/rBAbb0936969d2a809c0d10e360b59c76e28b5a7f58). Since Blender 2.83(beta) it works properly.

Answer (score 2):

I had this. For whatever reason it unticks merge in your mirror modifier.

Comment: Just press again the merge function in the mirror modified does not seem to work

Answer (score 2):

Based on the opinion of the user above I managed to solve the problem. It seems like if I apply the mirror setting before playing with the LoopTools and after that selecting all the vertexes will lead to a smooth round shape instead of the square. So, in the end, it seems like indeed the problem is the fact that once LoopTool is applied it deactivates the mirror function leading to that shape.

So once you apply the mirror setting you will no longer have 5 vertexes in the middle but 20. Select all ofthem and then apply the circle option from LoopTool. That should solve the problem.